# how to translate parenthesis mark in XPath?

Tags: xpath, translate, parentheses

I try to `translate(translate(tag, '(', ''),')','')`, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to delete or change symbol `(` ?

Best regards.

Comment: @Jirka's answer is probably what you need. You could post a sample XML document that you're working on so that we can verify. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate

Comment: Don't tell us that something "doesn't work". Tell us what the effect is: wrong answer? error message? Downvoting because this really makes the question hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to simplify it and following seems to be working

```
translate(tag, '()', '')
```

for input `ab(c(d)e)f` it gives me result `abcdef`